# Keep any number in boundaries

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I want to be able to have a class in Python that stores three values. A value, a min value, and a max value. The goal with this is to have a method called `addVal()` which takes a number and adds it to the current value, the catch is if the number plus the value we are shifting our current value by is greater than our stored max, it wraps around to the min and keeps going.

This is the class I have so far:

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, min = 0, max = 26, val = 0):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self.val = val

    def setMin(self, min):
        self.min = min

    def setMax(self, max):
        self.max = max

    def addVal(self, num):
        if num+self.val > self.max:
            # Only works with values when num%max + val is greater than max
            self.val = min + (num%val - (max-(num%val)))
        else:
            self.val += num
```

For example:

```
num = Num(0, 65, 60) # num = Num(min, max, val)
num.val # returns 60
num.addVal(15)
num.val # returns 10 (because we can use 5 of the 15 before going over the max and having a remaining ten to add to the min)
num.addVal(20)
num.val # returns 30
num.addVal(265)
num.val # # returns 35
```

All of this needs to work with negative values too of any size..I cannot figure an elegant solution for this..

I would LOVE to get a one-liner that works with any value but I can't figure out the quite right combination to get it to work with any value..certainly I can brute force it to make basic calculations on modulus operations and get it to work with some logic structure in the various cases that can arise however I would love to find an extremely simple elegant solution that just works out of the box blindly with any value.

Here is my current class:

Answer (score 2):

Your wraparound number can be computed by removing an offset of `min` from the value and then doing the addition `mod (max - min)` before adding the offset back in again. Here's code that should work for any values of `num`, `val` and `min` and `max` (so long as `min < max`):

```
def addVal(self, num):
    self.val = self.min + (self.val + num - self.min) % (self.max - self.min)
```

Comment: And heck, if you want elegant -- why not just override `__iadd__`? `my_num = Num(min=0, max=26, val=3); my_num += 25; my_num == 2 # True`